# Woocommerce: Showing Categories on every page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I am using the woocommerce plugin for a wordpress site.  The categories of the shop should be listed on the left part of the page and the categories on the right side.

When the shop page first loads, it is displayed as above.  Which is good.  When I click on the category it only shows the products and not the categories.

Is there an easy way to get the categories on every page?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your category and set **Display type** to **Both**.

Default setting can be set in Settings page under Catalog tab.